# Interpretation of reaction-diffusion's equation and Dirichlet condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

I am studiyng some PDE's for biology and I wish to understand how to interpret the difussion-reaction equation and the Dirichlet problem.

Let $\Omega$ a regular domain of $\mathbb{R}^2$, delimiting an area of the species where $N$ substances diffuse by interacting with each other. Densites are noted $\rho_1,\dots,\rho_N$ and verify the equations:

$$\partial_t \rho_i - D_iΔ\rho_i=F_i(\rho_1,\dots,\rho_N)\; \text{in}\; \Omega,\, i=1,2,\dots,N,$$

where the $D_i>0$ are the diffusion coefficients for each of the species, and the functions

$$F_i:(\rho_1,\dots,\rho_N)\to F_i(\rho_1,\dots,\rho_N)$$

model the terms of reactions between species. We will give initial contions
$$\rho_i(t=0)=\rho_i^0\geq 0.$$

We will first consider homogeneous Dirichlet conditions:
$$\rho_i =0\;\text{on}\; \partial\Omega.$$

Questions:

1. Specify the meaning (in terms of modeling) of the homogeneous
   Dirichlet condition.
2. Write the material balance for the species $\rho_i$, and explain why, if
   we admit that the $\rho_i$ will remain positive over time, the
   prescription of this type of condition corresponds to a
   disappearance of material.

For the question 1.

I thought that the Dirichlet condition means that the environment outside the domain $\Omega$ is so hostile that any organism crossing the border dies immediately.

For the question 2. part of material balance: I thought like this 
$$\text{quantity of substance contained in}\; \Omega=n(t)=\int_\Omega\rho_i(t,x)dx$$
and we consider a substance which propagates according to the flux vector $J$. Then

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_\Omega\rho_i(t,x)dx=-\int_{\partial\Omega}J\cdot n =-\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot J$$

and

$$\partial_t\rho_i + \nabla\cdot J =0$$

Can someone help me?

References for books are much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For books, use J.D Murray 'Mathematical Biology' volumes I and II. I'm pretty sure vol I answers both your questions.

Comment: For books, use Lionel Roques 'Modèles de réaction-diffusion pour l'écologie spatiale: Avec exercices dirigés'. pages 48, 49, 50.